# Combine .withLatestFrom with a single-value Observable

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

In an ngrx/store Angular app I need to act imperatively in one place and I need to grab the latest value from store and pass it further.

I need to somehow use `.withLatestFrom()`, knowing that it is not a static method.

So I thought I would combine `.withLatestFrom()` operator with a simple `Observable.of(null)`. This doesn't work though. Don't really know why.

So this will work:

```
Observable.of(null)
  .do(val => console.log('value', val))
  .subscribe();
```

but combining it will not:

```
Observable.of(null)
  .withLatestFrom(this.myStoreValues$)
  .do(args => console.log('with', args))
  .subscribe();
```

Is there a workaround for it?

Comment: what is `this.myStoreValues$`?

Comment: "I need to act imperatively in one place..." Why?

Comment: it is an Observable created from a store selector, as in: `this.myStoreValues = this.store.select(getMyStoreValues)` I just discovered that it has `.share()` on it, and when I remove `.share()` the code starts to work. Don't quite get it.

Answer (score 0):

The combineLatest operator should help you. Essentially it streams the output from multiple sources when there is a change. In your case, your only stream can be combined as below.

```
Observable.combineLatest(this.myStoreValues$)
.do(args => console.log('with', args))
  .subscribe();
```